# Application Not Running properly in Xcode 4.1 Version and Mac 10.6.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode

One of my clients handed over an application to me for some changes. But when I ran the application it gave me (1347) errors which are not code related. Some Errors are shown below:

```
CG_EXTERN const CFStringRef kCGPDFContextCropBox
  CG_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_4, __IPHONE_2_0);
CG_EXTERN const CFStringRef kCGPDFContextSubject
  CG_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);
```

Comment: Those are just declarations; what do the actual errors say?

Comment: first Error which i see this ,but i already sad its not look like code Error.its some thing about Framework or About Xcode or Mac version.                                                           : expected declaration specifiers before '__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__MAC_10_7'